# How to draw an arc with Qt?

Tags: qt, qpainter, qtgui, qrect

Consider the following diagram:

**I have information about the center point of both the lines, the angle in between, and the length of both the lines.**

The issue is to draw an arc starting at the end of the bottom line and touching the above slanting line *(the way shown below)*:

```
     /
    /
   /
  /.
 /  .
/___.
```

I saw these arc drawing functions of Qt:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawArc

These functions need a rectangle as an argument where as I don't have any.

**How should I use these functions to draw the arc as shown above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QPointF O; // intersection of lines
QPointF B; // end point of horizontal line
QPointF A; // end point of other line

float halfSide = B.x-O.x;
QRectF rectangle(O.x - halfSide,
                 O.y - halfSide,
                 O.x + halfSide,
                 O.y + halfSide);

int startAngle = 0;
int spanAngle = (atan2(A.y-O.y,A.x-O.x) * 180 / M_PI) * 16;

QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawArc(rectangle, startAngle, spanAngle);
```

You have to calculate the boundary rectangle, than the angle between the lines using atan.